# How to deserialize a binary-serialized NameValueCollection in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, deserialization, namevaluecollection

We have an existing SQL Server database with a field that contains binary-serialized instances of NameValueCollection.  The serialization was done using C# code based on .NET Framework (where NameValueCollection was marked as [Serializable]).

Our code has now been ported to .NET 5, where NameValueCollection is no longer marked as [Serializable].  This means that we cannot deserialize the data written using the old code-base.

```
Type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' in Assembly 'System.Collections.Specialized, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
```

Is there anyway, in .NET 5 (or .NET 6), to read the NameValueCollections from the database?

Obviously we could write a converter in .NET Framework that would change the binary-serialized data to JSON-serialized, however we would like to avoid this if at all possible (for reasons).

Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot you write a desrializer with has raw binary data as input? I think you know the data sequence as they were written

Comment: what was the .net framework version you were using?

Comment: The data was originally created with .net 4.7

Comment: @MarcoBeninca Possibly, although how do I do this for a NameValueCollection that is full of string/string pairs?

Comment: @oclipa I really don't know... you need some reverse engineering

Comment: I have the same issue with quartz. It works in .Net Framework 4.(whatever), but it does not work in .Net 6 because of it. Do you have solution?

Comment: No, sorry.  In the end, we converted all of the binary-serialized data to json-serialized.